# Integration: Why does the integration yield $R/\Psi$?

Tags: integration

Let $\Psi=(x,t)$ and $R=R(x,t)$ and consider
$$
\Psi_xR-\Psi R_x=0.
$$

Now, it is said that integrating over $x$, gives
$$
\frac{R}{\Psi}=h(t)
$$
for some function $h(t)$.

Don't see that!
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Psi_x R-\Psi R_x\, dx=h(t)
$$
is clear, but why is the left-hand side $R/\Psi$?

Do you have an idea?

I only see that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{R}{\Psi}=\frac{R_x\Psi - R\Psi_x}{\Psi^2}
$$
so that I can instead consider the equation
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty R_x\Psi-R\Psi_x\, dx=g(t):=-h(t)
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty R_x\Psi-R\Psi_x\, dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Psi^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{R}{\Psi}\right)\, dx
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\Psi$ is nonzero, you can divide through by $-\Psi^2$ to get
$$
\frac{\Psi R_x - R\Psi_x}{\Psi^2}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{R}{\Psi}\right) = 0.
$$
Then do an indefinite integration with respect to $x$ to get
$$
\frac{R}{\Psi} = h,
$$
where $h$ is some function that does not depend on $x$ (analogous to the constant of integration in single-variable indefinite integrals). Since $t$ is the only other variable it can depend on, we must have
$$
\frac{R}{\Psi} = h(t)
$$
for some single-variable function $h$.